# how to get route optimization from multiple destinations Google maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am Developing Android application in which i need to show available destinations to the user in Google Maps and provide route optimization with near and far destinations.
And Also set priorities to each and every destination LIKE eg:(1,5,3,2,4,6,7) etc.

Please can anyone help me on this topic.

Comment: first you calculate minimum distance between two lat long and then draw route on this lat long

Comment: i knw but how do i get routes of multiple destinations.. this is what my problem is..

Comment: use for Each loop and draw multiple destination route draw

Comment: ok if you could provide me code it could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think this [tutorial](http://clokey2k.com/articles/2012/displaying-multiple-routes-using-google-maps-api/) can help you with your problem. It uses a [Google Maps JavaScript Direction Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Directions). What you need is to create a structure request object and pass it into to a Direction Service Object and wait for Google's servers to respond via your callback function. After checking that the directions are "OK", you can iterate through the results object or pass it to a [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer) Object provided by the Google API.

This tutorial gives you a sample code that will serve as a guide for you. For more information, you can also check this related SO question:

- [Using Google Maps 3 API to get multiple routes on a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304875/using-google-maps-3-api-to-get-multiple-routes-on-a-map)
- [Google maps API - adding multiple destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320701/google-maps-api-adding-multiple-destinations-not-working-google-directions)

Comment: thank u so much. i will look on this stuff..and let u know